# TinyCore in qemu save options

Tags: qemu, tinycore

I ran

```bash
qemu-system-x86_64 -m 2047M -boot d -hda tc.vhd -cdrom TinyCore-current.iso
```

I installed Firefox and shut down the virtual machine. After rebooting with
the same command, Firefox wasn't installed. How can I achieve that if I install something, it will persist in `tc.vhd` image? Has it something to do with the "save options" when shutting down the machine? There is a backup option, but it isn't offering the `/dev/hda` as I would expect.

Comment: looks like you're running in a "live CD" type scenario - imagine doing exactly that with an actual CD on an actual computer ... where do you think anything would be installed in that case?

Comment: I'm assuming it is due to booting off the CD ROM with `-boot d`.  Try booting from the hard drive instead (possibly using `-boot c`).  I'm not turning this into an answer as I currently have no way of testing it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using the backup and setting the boot option "restore=hda"?
Or some other equivalent from chapter 1.10.1 of http://www.tinycorelinux.net/book.html